# Activity not stopping for response

Tags: java, android

I am new to app development (android studio).
I have two classes one is main and the other class (database) which connects to firebase and checks if the user exists or not and replies true or false respectively and also prints out some statements.
The problem is the android studio does not wait for a response even if the task is successful and replies a false.
print statement I should be getting in the logcat should be 
"here 1", "here 2", and then "here 3". but it gives me "here 2", "here 3" and then "here 1".

I know it has to do something with threading or something like that.

```
public class loginpage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button Login;
    private EditText user_email_txt;
    private EditText user_password_txt;
    private ProgressBar wait_bar;
    private String[] user_name_password ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        find_all_views();

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getuser_login_details();
                disable_all_views();
                Activate_wait_bar();
                final Database login = new Database();
                boolean decision = login.sign_in(user_name_password[0], user_name_password[1]);
                System.out.println("here 3");
            }
        });

    }

    private void find_all_views() {
        user_email_txt =  findViewById(R.id.UserName);
        user_password_txt = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        Login = findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
        wait_bar =  findViewById(R.id.wait_bar);
    }

    private void getuser_login_details() {
        user_name_password =  new String[2];
        user_name_password[0] = user_email_txt.getText().toString();
        user_name_password[1] = user_password_txt.getText().toString();
    }

    private void disable_all_views() {
        user_email_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        user_password_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void Activate_wait_bar() {
        wait_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

```
public class Database  {
    private FirebaseAuth connect_databse;
    private boolean authorisation;
    public Database() {}

    public boolean sign_in(String user_name, String Password) {
        authorisation = false;
        connect_databse = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        connect_databse.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_name, Password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = connect_databse.getCurrentUser();
                            authorisation =  true;
                            System.out.println("here 1");
                        }
                    }
                });
        System.out.println("here 2");
       return authorisation;
    }
}
```

if the task is successful it should return authorization = true with print statements "here 1", "here 2", and then "here 3" in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new file:

```
interface OnCompleteListener {
    void onComplete();
}
```

In Database class:

```
 public class Database {

private FirebaseAuth connect_databse;

private boolean authorisation;

public Database() {

}

public void sign_in(String user_name, String Password,final OnCompleteListener listener) {

    authorisation = false;

    connect_databse = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    connect_databse.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user_name, Password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = connect_databse.getCurrentUser();
                        authorisation =  true;
                        System.out.println("here 1");
                        listener.onComplete();
                        System.out.println("here 2");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

In Activity:

```
Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        getuser_login_details();

            disable_all_views();

            Activate_wait_bar();

           final Database login = new Database();

           boolean decision = login.sign_in(user_name_password[0], user_name_password[1], new OnCompleteListener{
               @Override
               public void onComplete(){
                    System.out.println("here 3");
               }
           });

        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, its printing now. also gave me an idea of interfaces and callbacks.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve it. please mark it as correct and upvote it. Thanks @zaif687

Answer (score 0):

When you work with Network Connection or Call an API to get data from a server, you must use Background Thread and after the task completed, your code in `OnComplete` run. but main Thread doesn't stop for your task and run all code out of `OnComplete` method sequentially.

In this situation, you can use `CallBackMethod`.